# compareTo method won't compile

Tags: java, interface, comparable, compareto

My class header:

```
public class GraphEdge implements Comparable<GraphEdge>{

/** Node from which this edge starts*/
protected Point from;
/** Node to which this edge goes*/
protected Point to;
/** Label or cost for this edge*/
protected int cost;
```

My compareTo method:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(GraphEdge other){
    return this.cost-other.cost;
}
```

but Eclipse gives me the error:

The method compareTo(GraphEdge) of type GraphEdge must override a superclass method

whyyyyy?
I tried just doing Comparable, with

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Object o){
            GraphEdge other = (GraphEdge) o;
    return this.cost-other.cost;
}
```

but this also failed.

Comment: Can you post the error you are receiving?

Comment: that is the exact text of the error I am receiving.

Comment: You mention that your second attempt also failed but don't post an error message for that one. Are you receiving the same error?

Comment: Could you check if this is the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223512/comparatorstring-must-override-super-class-method

Comment: Is that a run time or compile error? I am running your first implementation and its seems to work. Might need to see how your using it to help.

Comment: Yes, that was it... I read that question but somehow it just didn't register. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely your project is set to Java 1.5 compliance level - try setting it to 1.6 and it should work. Don't have Eclipse here to test, however I remember that when set to 1.5 I could not use @Override on interface (but could on class) method overriding. This worked OK when set to 1.6.

I.e. this should fail when set to 1.5, but work OK when on 1.6:

```
interface A {
   void a();
}

class B implements A {
   @Override
   public void a() {
   }
}
```

So try it:

- http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-with-j2se50.htm

[image]

Comment: More likely providing a duplicate answer from another question here on SO should be avoided :) Check my comment on OP's question..

Comment: @Jack What's interesting is that answer says that it's not **supported** on interface methods on 1.5, however I just tested myself with `javac -source 1.5 -target 1.5` and it compiled OK - true, with javac v1.6.0_26-b03, however the problem seems a bit more ambiguous. And to note - I did run into this myself, but was never sure whether that was Eclipse issue or Java issue.

Comment: My working code got bit by the 1.5 compliance level on my new Eclipse install.  After changing it to 1.6 per icyrock, I also had to change my project Facet version to 1.6 as well, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239959/faceted-project-prblem-java-version-mismatch-error-message.