# Eclipse: JRE System Library in Java Build Path reset

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, buildpath, java-8

For developing a JavaFX application I'm using a [4.3.1 snapshot of eclipse](http://downloads.efxclipse.org/eclipse-java8/2013-09-13/) together with JDK 8 build b116. 
In my workspace projects the JRE library inclusion in the build path get resetted back to Java 1.4 all the time:

[image: the problem]

Unfortunately, this can only be fixed temporary (until the next eclipse restart):

[image: the temporary solution]

In the build section of my pom files I have:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <debug>true</debug>
        <debuglevel>source,lines</debuglevel>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I'd appreciate a less volatile solution.

**[UPDATE]** The issue seems to be fixed with the current versions of

- Java 8 (1.8.0-ea-b121),
- Maven (3.1.1/1.5.0.20131218-0705),
- m2e (1.5.0.20131218-1208) together with the
- JDT beta patch [[Update site](http://dist.springsource.com/snapshot/TOOLS/java8/e43)].

Comment: Change the java version in project facet to 1.8. May be you can try to run the eclipse to use java 1.8( I don't think this will have any impact). Pom.xml dependency looks fine

Comment: @Jens have you been able to resolve this issue? I am in the same situation now with Eclipse 4.3, Maven 3.2.1 and JDK 1.8.0b129.

Comment: @RAM: I update my post with some details about my current (working) versions, hopefully that helps.

Comment: The Install Instructions from https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_8_Support_%28BETA%29 seem to work. I can use Java 8 features but the Execution Environment of the Maven project is still listed as J2SE-1.4.

Comment: Same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22696067/eclipse-4-3-2-with-java-8-patches-doesnt-recognize-source-level-1-8/23003292#23003292 ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maven eclipse plugin (m2e) selects a java execution environment depending on the `<source>` and `<target>` properties for the maven compiler plugin.

The problem is that there is neither a 1.8 execution environment available in Kepler nor the m2e maven compiler connector can map it yet.

Thus I see two solutions until it is supported in Kepler and m2e:

1. Let maven change the environment to 1.4 and map your 1.8 JDK to the execution environment J2SE-1.4. Then your project will use the correct JDK. But then all projects that depend on 1.4 will use the 1.8 JDK of course.
2. Use the `pluginManagenent` to turn off the `maven-compiler-plugin` lifecycle handling. This should prevent the m2e plugin from updating the execution environment and you can set it manually.

   ```
   <pluginManagement>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
               <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
               <version>1.0.0</version>
               <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                          <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                                          <versionRange>[1.0.0,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>compile</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                         <ignore />
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                          </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </pluginManagement>
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. It looks like the second option solves the problem. It just worries me a little, that Mavens *Updating Project* now throws an `java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.lifecyclemapping.model.PluginExecutionFilter.match(PluginExecutionFilter.java:337)` ...

Comment: Hmm, that was not what I expected. I will take a look at it later or tomorrow.

Comment: I also got the NPE and updated my answer. The NPE should be gone now and you should still be able to set the execution environment manually.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to this. Now, the pom file editor shows the error `Cannot parse lifecycle mapping metadata for maven project`. :-/

Comment: @JensPiegsa The parse exception you have is caused by the `goals` and `versionRange` tag. I updated my answer. But if the `lifecycleMappingMetadata` is correct than m2e will update the execution environment again. Thus it does not work to use the `lifecycleMappingMetadate` to turn it off. So there is only one option left, nr. 1 as I proposed. Hope that helps you anyway.

Comment: Well, with option 1, I have to correct the compliance level manually. Thanks for the effort, though. Let us be patient until Eclipse, Maven and m2e officially support version 8.